# Notification is not showing in my app in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I want to set my `location(home)` and when I enter in that `location(home)` then the app will give me a notification with sound (Hi! I am at home). Using `KitLocate` (geoFence) in eclipse but it is not showing notification. I can't find what the problem is. My MainActivity.java file is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        KitLocate.initKitLocate(this, "584da03d-18d7-4701-9808-eec48f65e797");

        KLLocation.addGeofence(this, 31.54381f, 74.28253f, 5, KLGeofence.Type.IN,"Home");   

        KLLocation.registerGeofencing(this, GeofenceCallbackHandler.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        KLApplication.onActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        KLApplication.onActivityStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

GeofenceCallbackHandler. java

```
public class GeofenceCallbackHandler implements IKLGeofenceResponse{

    @Override
    public void geofenceIn(Context arg0, ArrayList<KLGeofence> arg1) {
        new KLLocalNotification(arg0, "Hi, I am at home", R.drawable.ic_launcher).setDefaultSound(true).setContentTitle("Geofence in").send();

    }

    @Override
    public void geofenceInArm(Context arg0, ArrayList<KLGeofence> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void geofenceOut(Context arg0, ArrayList<KLGeofence> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void geofenceOutArm(Context arg0, ArrayList<KLGeofence> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nabia.geofencetry"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <service android:name="com.kl.kitlocate.services.KLLocationService" android:label="KitLocate Service"/>
            <service android:name="com.kl.kitlocate.services.KLAccelerometerService" android:label="KitLocate IDLE Service"/>
            <service android:name="com.kl.kitlocate.services.KLRescueService" android:label="KitLocate Rescue Service"/>
            <receiver android:name="com.kl.kitlocate.receivers.KLBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>                


    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nabia.geofencetry.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me, what should I do?